# Trouble Binding WpfToolKit Watermark Textbox Using Prism

Tags: c#, wpf, prism, wpftoolkit

So, I've been spending way too much time on this trying to figure out what I am doing wrong. I am pretty new to Prism too. I've looked at other peoples binding examples, but none of them seem to work. What doesn't make since to me is what I bind it inside the "Text=" and go to click on another textbox my text clears. I've tried TwoWay Mode, UpdatePropertyChange, etc. Nothing seems to work. I've even put break points to see if the value does indeed match the cs code. But no, it doesn't bind. What am I doing wrong? I just want my textbox to equal my viewmodels "UserName" string value so what someone clicks on the login button, it checks the values to see if they exist in a database.

Here is Login.xaml:

```
        <Grid x:Name="UserInputGrid"
          Margin="15" 
          Height="100">
        <wpfTool:WatermarkTextBox  x:Name="UsernameTextBox" 
                                   Width="600"
                                   Height="100"
                                   Text="{Binding UserName}"
                                   Watermark="Username"
                                   Cursor="IBeam" 
                                   FontFamily="Quicksand" 
                                   FontSize="72"/>
    </Grid>
```

LoginView.xaml.cs

```
    public LoginView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new LoginViewModel();
    }
}
```

LoginViewModel.cs:

```
public class LoginViewModel : BindableBase
{
    #region Private Variables

    //Private Variables

    bool isCanLogin = true;
    private string _username;
    private string _password;
    #endregion

    #region Public Variables

    //Public Variables

    public string UserName
    {
        get { return _username; }
        set { RaisePropertyChanged("UserName"); }
    }
    public string Password
    {
        get { return _password; }
        set { RaisePropertyChanged("Password"); }
    }
    public bool CanLogin() { return isCanLogin; }

    #endregion

    #region Commands

    //Commands

    RelayCommand _loginCommand;
    public ICommand LoginCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_loginCommand == null)
                _loginCommand = new RelayCommand(Login, CanLogin);

            return _loginCommand;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Functions and Methods

    //Functions and Methods

    private void Login()
    {
        try
        {
            isCanLogin = false;
            SoundPlayers.ButtonSound();
            //Authentication and Checks the DB to see if the User exists

            if (AuthenticationService.VerifyUser(UserName, Password))
            {
                //Navigate to landing page
                SoundPlayers.LoginSound();
            }
            else
            {
                //Doesn't exist!?!
            }

            isCanLogin = true;
        }
        catch
        {
            //If Login requirements aren't met, or failed
        }
        finally
        {
            isCanLogin = true;
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: *"What doesn't make since to me is what I bind it inside the "Text=" and go to click on another textbox my text clears."* -- Are you saying that you type text into `UsernameTextBox`, and then when it loses focus, it discards the text that you typed into the box?

Comment: Yes, the only way it stays is if I do Mode=OneWay, I'm looking at another example, and they do twoway. But anything I do, when I put my cursor over the value UserName to see if it has the value I typed in the textbox, it says "Null". (This is when I put a break point down.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your property setters to something like the following:

```
public string UserName
{
    get { return _username; }
    set { SetProperty(ref _username, value); }
}
```

With this technique, you do not have to call the `RaisePropertyChanged`, it is done for you. And, the backing variable gets set if it has changed.

The `SetProperty` method comes from the `Prism.Mvvm` namespace.

Comment: @jtreimer You should accept it as the correct answer when the system lets you.

Answer (score 0):

Your setters are broken. They never update the private backing field. The control is correctly updating your property via the Binding, but the property doesn't save the value that comes in. You'll need to update `Password` similarly.

```
public string UserName
{
    get { return _username; }
    set {
        if (_username != value)
        {
            _username = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("UserName");
        }
    }
}
```